# CustomValidator on server control rendering inside tags of parent element

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a `RadEditor` and I'm trying to add a `CustomValidator` to it, as so:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    var validator = new CustomValidator();
    validator.CssClass = "validator-error";
    validator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
    validator.ControlToValidate = ".";
    validator.Text = "You've exceeded the maximum allowed length for this field";
    validator.ClientValidationFunction = "radEditorCheckLength";

    this.Controls.Add(validator);

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Which works fine, however when it renders, the validator is actually rendering *inside* the `RadEditor`.  How do I make it appear before the `RadEditor` element?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a total hack. Does it work?

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    this.validator.RenderControl(writer);
    this.validator.Visible = false;
    base.Render(writer);
    this.validator.Visible = true;
}
```

You'll need to store your `CustomValidator` in a field:

```
private CustomValidator validator;

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.validator = new CustomValidator();
    // ...
}
```

(I disassembled `RadEditor` in Reflector, but I didn't see an easy way to modify `RenderChildren` to skip rendering the validator.)